# Google Sheets Script To Dynamically Set Row Height

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Form that is dumping data into this Google Sheet.  The data from the form can be very long, with paragraph breaks which causes the row height to be very very tall.

So I found the following script and it works (mostly), except that if I set the second number (35 in this case, aka 'num_rows') to 999 it says it's out of bounds.

```
function ResizeRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Sets the rows to height of 21 pixels
sheet.setRowHeightsForced(2, 35, 21);
}
```

Is there a way I can have the num_rows portion be dynamic so it'll run no matter if the sheet has 50 or 100 rows?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you can only set height of existing rows.

Besides, it seems the row height set in advance does not apply to rows appended upon new responses.

You may consider to `setRowHeightsForced` with a `onSubmit` function.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I added a maxrows function and subtracted one since I'm ignoring the top (header) row.

```
function ResizeRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This example assumes there is a sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var form = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var total = form.getMaxRows()-1;

// Sets the rows to height of 21 pixels
sheet.setRowHeightsForced(2, total, 21);
}
```